# why buffer memory allocation error in opencl

Tags: c, memory-management, opencl, nvidia

I execute the OpenCL program on an NDRange with a work-group size of 16*16 and work-global size of 1024*1024. The application is matrix multiplication.
When the two input matrix size are both little, it works well. But when the size of input matrix becomes large, for example, larger than 20000*20000, it reports error "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE" in the function of enqueuendrangekernrl.

I am puzzled. I am not familiar with memory allocation. What's the reason?

Comment: so ,are you create a memory (20000*20000)*(16*16) byte?

Comment: the reason? i check the return value of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, and it is CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE. I am still puzzled.

Comment: I think its 200000*200000*4 byte, the type is float and gpu address is 32 bit. so total storage is more than 1 Gb. So it is too large to result in this error

Comment: so you already konw what's wrong.

Comment: Also there need to be three matrices for mult. which makes more than 4 GB which is too big. You should divide the matrix into sub-matrices and compute part by part.

Answer (score 2):

With **clGetDeviceInfo**, you can query the device global memory size with **CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE**, and the maximum size you can alloc in a single memory object with **CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE**. Three matrices of 20000*20000*sizeof(float) = 1.6 GB  probably exceed these limits.